# ERROR reading multidict in python server?

Tags: python, server-side-scripting

i have a server in python that is recieving data in following format:

```
  MultiDict([('JSONdata', u'{"SMS":[{"inbox":[{"body":"BACKUP *qqqqq*","phone":"+920000000"},{"body":"BACKUP *qqqqq*","phone":"+920000000"},{"body":"BACKUP *qqqqq*","phone":"+920000000"},{"body":"BACKUP *qqqqq*","phone":"+920000000"},{"body":"BACKUP *qqqqq*","phone":"+920000000"},{"body":"BACKUP *qqqqq*","phone":"+920000000"},{"body":"BACKUP *qqqqq*","phone":"+920000000"},{"body":"BACKUP *qqqqq*","phone":"+920000000":"BACKUP *qqqqq*","phone":"+920000000"},{"body":"BACKUP \\"qqqqq\\"    ","phone":"+920000000"},{"body":"BACKUP \\"qqqqq\\"   ","phone":"+920000000"},{"body":"BACKUP \\"qqqqq\\"  ","phone":"+920000000"},]},{"sent":[]}]}')])
```

i have written the following code to fetch it and convert it in JSONObject:

```
   request.POST.getall('JSONdata')
    incomingData = json.load(str)
```

but i am recieving the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 85, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/anam/pyckenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/router.py", line 251, in __call__
    response = self.invoke_subrequest(request, use_tweens=True)
  File "/home/anam/pyckenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/router.py", line 227, in invoke_subrequest
    response = handle_request(request)
  File "/home/anam/cdsr/myproject/auth.py", line 50, in auth_request
    return handler(request)
  File "/home/anam/pyckenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_debugtoolbar/toolbar.py", line 130, in toolbar_tween
    return handler(request)
  File "/home/anam/pyckenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/tweens.py", line 21, in excview_tween
    response = handler(request)
  File "/home/anam/pyckenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 82, in tm_tween
    reraise(*exc_info)
  File "/home/anam/pyckenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid_tm/__init__.py", line 63, in tm_tween
    response = handler(request)
  File "/home/anam/pyckenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/router.py", line 161, in handle_request
    response = view_callable(context, request)
  File "/home/anam/pyckenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/config/views.py", line 347, in rendered_view
    result = view(context, request)
  File "/home/anam/pyckenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyramid/config/views.py", line 493, in _requestonly_view
    response = view(request)
  File "/home/anam/cdsr/myproject/controllers/controllers.py", line 44, in data
    incomingData = json.load(str)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 274, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'read'
QMobile-A8 - - [11/Oct/2013 08:24:08] "POST /data HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

i have tried different ways to solve it but nothings working.. ??? could someone tell me what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) says that `load` function

> Deserialize a .read()-supporting file-like object containing a JSON document

and are giving it string instead.

You need `loads` (LOAD String) function from `json` module

Comment: thanks .. but after doing that error changed to ...   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: edit question to show what is inside `MultiDict` instance, please and what does `request.POST.getall('JSONdata')` return

Comment: i have added complete incoming multidict

Comment: It is something wrong with your string. You should check its validity.

Comment: i have tried sending a simple JSONObject MultiDict([('JSONdata', u'{"name":"1234"}')])
still its giving error .. File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 366, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer